# Real closed field with the restricted exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, logic, quantifier-elimination

Is the theory of real closed fields augmented with the restricted exponential function decidable?  If so, can someone explain that decision procedure?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what precise theory you are asking about. If the question is whether the theory of $(\mathbb{R}, +, \times, \exp)$ is decidable, this is still open (see [Tarksi's exponential function problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_exponential_function_problem) on Wikipedia), but a positive answer would follow from Schanuel's conjecture [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), a very powerful conjecture in number theory.

Comment: There is a bit of a difference.  I am using the restricted exponential function, while Tarski's exponential function problem uses the full function.  The restricted exponential function is equal to the regular exponential function on [-1,1] but is zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of $(\mathbb{R},\exp|_{[0,1]})$ of $\mathbb{R}$ by the restricted exponential function has a model-complete theory.

[Encyclopedia of Mathematics: Model theory of the real exponential function](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Model_theory_of_the_real_exponential_function)

[Wilkie, A. J.: Model completeness results for expansions of the ordered field of real numbers by restricted Pfaffian functions and the exponential function. J. Amer. Math. Soc. 9 (1996) (4)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.323.6545)